# How to count a call to a Webservice on Function Point

Tags: function-points

I have a program inside the boundary of the application that makes a call to a webservice outside the border.

Problem is: I have two experts disagreeing on how it should be counted.

1 - One argues that Webservice is just a data access method (like a RDBMS) and thus should be counted as an external file (i.e. as a data function)

2- The other argues that the CPM defines that a user can be an application and this is a transaction function. Calling the webservice would be similar to presenting a screen to a human user.

None can produce proof in the official documentation available to define who is right (except that ISO/IEC 14143-1:2007 - Functional size measurement actually says that an application can be a user)

Can anyone help to settle the argument (based on availble documents)?

I have only access to the two experts.

Comment: are you asking for an opinion to settle a disagreement of opinions?

Comment: Lol. No. Maybe I was not clear. 
What I need is a official reference that settles the dispute. 
There should be a document somewhere that say how to count a webservice.

Comment: I am no expert in the field, but I see no difference between the two ... data is crossing the application boundary in both arguments